# How to set the height of table to be the size of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a table in HTML and CSS that has its own scrollbars (as opposed to the page's scrollbars).

```
<div class = "results">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th>Header4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value3</td>
        <td>Value4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.results {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 600px;
}
```

This achieves what I want but only on my screen. If I look at this table on another screen or resolution then the bottom scrollbar is in a different position. How do I make sure the bottom scrollbar is always at the bottom of the screen? I tried doing this with percentages instead and the bottom bar doesn't appear at all. I also tried doing `vh` instead of `px` but that just does the same thing. I can't seem to figure out how to make sure the bottom scrollbar will always be on the bottom of the screen. It seems I have to explicitly set the height in order for the table to have its own scrollbars.

I also tried setting the height to `auto` but that makes it so I can't scroll at all. It looks like the height has to be a specific value.

Using `vh` is a lot better than using `px` but the bottom bar still doesn't always appear at the bottom.

Comment: have you tried position fixed?

Comment: I think `vh` is the unit you're looking for

Comment: A slight mistake in my question. I did mean ```vh``` and that just does the exact same thing as ```px``` (where the position is different depending on the screen size).

Comment: I also tried position fixed and the scrollbars don't appear at all.

Comment: Try height: 100vh; to table

Comment: You mean use height 100vh on the table selector? I tried it on the results div as well as on the table selector and neither one worked (it still changes positions).

Comment: It seems that there is content above the table, that's why it is difficult to do with css. There are many different display aspect ratios. Also a browser can be resized in any size (width and height). I think this has to be done with javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ViewHeight and ViewPort units to specify width and height of elements relative to the ones of the viewport, where 100vw is all of the viewports width. Same with Viewheight, 100vh is all of the viewports height.

here's the mdn reference for `Units`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

```css
.results{
  height:100vh;
}
```

**Edit**

A very common problem with vw and vh is that, they don't take into consideration, things like padding, and margin. you'll have to manualy subtract those values with `calc()`

Let's say the sum of all the cellspacing, margin and padding is 20px

```css
.results{
    height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

And yes calc works with all units.

Comment: It's hard to tell if that does the trick because the bottom scrollbar is off the screen. I tried to set it to different resolutions and the scrollbar is still off the screen (so it might work) but I even tried padding and I can't get the scrollbar to appear again. The problem is that in the actual code, the table does not take up 100% of the screen.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly. Everyone kept making this out to be so complex but that's all it took. It's now perfectly glued to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom then you can use this css. Here I'm using the flexbox instead of the old tablebox for having much more flexibility.

```css
.results {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.results * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.results table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.results thead, .results tbody {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.results tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
.results th, .results td {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;  /* column width */
  max-width: 25%; /* column width */
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
/* below for smartphone */
@media (max-width: 767.9px) {
  .results table {
    border: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = "results">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th>Header4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value3</td>
        <td>Value4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you have different width sizes for each column then you can use nth-child.
In your html you can use nth-child(1)...nth-child(4) like this

```
.results tr th:nth-child(1),
.results tr td:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  max-width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: The scrollbars still don't show up. The problem is that the table is being very stubborn about the fact that the scrollbars don't show up unless you explicitly set a height. You're setting alot of widths but it needs to be heights (unless I can change all of that to heights). At the moment, using ```vh``` seems to be my best bet as the scrollbar does kind of move with the screen but not exactly.

Comment: Sorry, in your question you mentioned the scrollbar at the bottom. It is good practice to have no bottom-scrollbar at all on all devices. If you do want the vertical scrollbar then use `overflow-y: visible;` (other properties are overflow-x and overflow). If you want a horizontal scrollbar on the table itself, then use `.results table { overflow-x: auto; }`

Comment: I actually don't want the bottom scrollbar to be part of the page but part of the actual table. This way I can scroll horizontally without scrolling the entire page. It's strange because the vertical scrollbar works fine but if I adjust the size of the window then the bottom horizontal scrollbar changes position. It seems like it's trying to correct the position if I use ```vh``` but it's still not glued to the bottom of the screen (which is the bottom of the table).

Comment: Maybe the best way is to adjust the breakbpoinnt where the table content overlaps the browser view `@media (max-width: 767.9px) { .... }` For example, change it in 991.9px . Then the css above will include a horizontal scrollbar on the table if the view is smaller then the content.